# Set dictionary keys as cells in dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

Please look at my code:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {
1 :{'a':5 , 'b':10},
5 :{'a':6 , 'b':67},
7 :{'a':33 , 'b':9},
8 :{'a':21 , 'b':37},
}

df = pd.DataFrame (my_dict).transpose()
df['new'] = df.index

print (df)
```

Here I convert dictionary to DataFrame and set index as new column.

```
    a   b  new
1   5  10    1
5   6  67    5
7  33   9    7
8  21  37    8
```

Can it be done in 1 line at the stage of converting a dictionary to a date without

```
df['new'] = df.index
```

I want to immediately recognize the major indices as cells of the new column.
Something like

```
df = pd.DataFrame (my_dict, 'new' = list(my_dict.keys()).transpose()
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict, orient='index')`

Comment: @Ch3steR, dear friend, index should be new column

Comment: chain index `.reset_index()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `reset_index()` to create a column from index and `df.rename` to change name of `index` column to `new` -

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict).transpose().reset_index().rename(columns={"index": "new"})
print(df)
```

```
   new   a   b
0    1   5  10
1    5   6  67
2    7  33   9
3    8  21  37
```

Comment: do mark it as correct if it solved your question. thanks.